# AutoComplete fixed selection?

Tags: java, android

How do i have an AutoComplete selection based on alphabetic instead of fixed switch cases? The situation is, everything working except when i input keyword with "B" showing Badrul as first suggestion but when clicked it will still refer to the first switch cases which is opening up Adidas.class instead of Badrul.class

Please help, i am new in this. Is AutoComplete suitable for my requirement?

```
public class Search extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSate)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceSate);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchshop);

        AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, shops);
        autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter); 
        autoComplete.setThreshold(1);
        autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
        {
            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(Search.this, Adidas.class));
                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(Search.this, Affin.class));
                break;
            case 2:
                startActivity(new Intent(Search.this, AlamArt.class));
                break;
            case 3:
                startActivity(new Intent(Search.this, Badrul.class));
                break;
            }
        }
        });     
    }
    static final String[] shops = new String[]
            {
                "Adidas", "Affin Bank", "Alam Art Gallery", "Badrul"
            };
}
```

Comment: Mr. Kenneth my answer only shows why you are facing the problem. Are you looking to fix this problem ? If yes i will post new answer.

Comment: Yes Yugandhar, it will be my honor. I been facing this problem for few days. Please do.

Comment: wait 10 mins. I will give you answer

Comment: are you happy. my solution and Hiral's solution both will work. But making final is not good, just think about it. Making global means we can access anywhere. correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obvious behavior as you are referring to the position of the suggestion at current time,so it would be differed according to what user types in. For achieving what you want,You need to change your code according to this:

```
public class Search extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSate)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceSate);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchshop);

        final AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, shops);
        autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter); 
        autoComplete.setThreshold(1);
        autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                int index=999;
                for(int i=0;i<shops.length;i++)
                {
                    if(autoComplete.getText().toString().trim().equals(shops[i]))
                    {
                         index=i;
                         break;
                    }               
                }
                switch(index)
                {
                    case 0:
                         startActivity(new Intent(Search.this, Adidas.class));
                         break;
                    case 1:
                         startActivity(new Intent(Search.this, Affin.class));
                         break;
                    case 2:
                         startActivity(new Intent(Search.this, AlamArt.class));
                         break;
                    case 3:
                         startActivity(new Intent(Search.this, Badrul.class));
                         break;
                    default:
                         Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Invalid Selection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
       });     
    }
    static final String[] shops = new String[]
    {
          "Adidas", "Affin Bank", "Alam Art Gallery", "Badrul"
    };
}
```

Comment: Hiral, i tried your solution from several days ago. ***if(autoComplete.getText().toString().trim().equals(shops[i]))
*** Is giving me cannot refer to a non-final variable autoComplete inside an inner class defined in a different method.

Comment: you just needed to make your autoComplete variable as final like final AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1); Making it like this will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: Wow, it worked perfectly. I did not thought of declaring from the AutoCompleteTextView, tried declaring static in autoComplete; and that prompt me local variable duplication error. Thank you Hiral! You make my day!

Answer (score 2):

You are adding **OnItemClickListener** to the **AutoCompleteTextView**. I think you don't know this thing about Item Click Listener.

The **position** variable in **onItemClick()** method stores the position of item clicked in the list shown.

You are telling the list shown **Badrul** as first suggestion, **so the position of item you clicked is 0**, so that its going to **case 0:**, so that its calling **Adidas.class**.

I hope you understood the problem from my answer.

Comment: So isit possible to have the position variable in onItemClick() to be able to follow selection accordingly to different alphabet?

Comment: At the moment what is the maximum switch cases for i able to implement?

Comment: not understood. asking generally about switch-case or for your problem ??

Comment: Generally about switch-case, currently i have created more than 100xml to be use with this autocomplete.

Comment: I don't know about no.of swtich statements but, case statements must have limit of maximum value of unsigned integer because, the case value is a number, i am telling this with my C knowledge, i am not much familiar with Java. It may wrong or right in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Kenneth The solution is already there, **Hiral**'s answer, but you have to modify it, to make **error free.**

Just do below changes.

Modify the below line of code into 2 parts.

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
```

1. Add below line of code before **onCreate()**

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete;
```

2.Modify the original line as below

```
autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
```

Comment: Noted, and with final of the Part1. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. No we can't accept more than one. Anyhow no problem. leave the answer to **Hiral**.